# Refer to object in second column

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to refer to object in second column (object *link_icon*) and based on .json data, I am assigning new url.

Structure of my html:

```
<div class="details">
    <h1 id="title">title</h1>
    <h3 id="author">
        <a href="https://www.google.pl/">author</a>
    </h3>
</div>
<a href="https://www.google.pl/">
    <div><i class="link_icon"></i></div>
</a>
```

---

```
$(function(){
  var url = 'img_and_data/' + randomNumbers[bgImgIndex] +'.json';
  var title = $("#title");// the id of the heading
  var author = $("#author a");// id of author
  var link_icon = $(".link_icon a"); // <------- problem probably is here 


  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    title.text(toTitleCase(data.title));
    author.text(data.copyright);
    author.attr("href", data.url);
    link_icon.attr("href", data.permalink);
  });
}
```

Here is my full code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/cvv0sen8/8/

How should I refer to `link_icon` to modify `href`?

Could you help me?

---

JSON:

```
{
    "title": "example title",  
    "copyright": "example author",
    "permalink": "https://www.bing.com/",
    "url": "http://www.yahoo.com"    
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle does not run because jQuery has not been added as a resource. Also `randomNumbers` is not defined in your fiddle. Please add it and make sure your fiddle runs before posting an example.

Comment: Can you include the contents of the json file specified in `url` in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> var link_icon = $(".link_icon a");

Your selector here means "every `a` tag which has a tag with class `link_icon` as a parent". Problem is your html document doesn't contain any `a` tag in `link_icon`: your selector will return nothing.

You may change your html like this:

```
<div><a class="link_a" href="#"><i class="link_icon"></i></a></div>
```

And your js:

```
var link_a = $(".link_a");

// ...

link_a.attr("href", data.permalink);
```

Comment: Thank you. 
I am not sure if I understand... without new class, just referring to _details_ as a parent class, I would modify every _a_ tag so, links under _author_ and link under _icon_ in the same time?